# JavaFX : Webkit appending file-paths instead of interpreting them.

Tags: java, css, javafx, path

I am working on a JavaFX project, in which I am loading an html page, which calls CSS file and loads some stuff. All the `html`, `images`, `css` files are in a separate directory called resources, which is in `src-->resources`. The Java files are in `src-->application-->Javafiles`.

When I directly run the application, I can see images loaded from CSS, but when I try to load it from a JAR file or an EXE file, then the paths are appended in a weird way.

What weird way?

SO, in Html, I call to load the css via `css/football.css`. Then the css is loaded. Now the image-path I am giving is `../img/image/ball.png` . When I directly run the application, it works, I can see the image. But as soon as I create a JAr or an EXE, path of the image becomes `/location_of_jar/resources/css../img/image/ball.png` . In this situation, the webkit browser should go one directory up, but instead it's just appending the paths. Why is that? How can i remedy this problem.

Code :

Football.html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/football.css"/>
```

Football.css :

```
background: url("../img/football/ball.png") no-repeat scroll center;
```

Loading index.html :

```
final String hellohtml = "/resources/index.html";

public MyBrowser() {
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                window.setMember("app", this);
                //webView.setEventDispatcher(webEventDispatcher);
            }
        });

        URL urlHello = getClass().getResource(hellohtml);

        webEngine.load(urlHello.toExternalForm());
        webView.setPrefSize(800, 600);
        webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);

         webView.getChildrenUnmodifiable().addListener((ListChangeListener<Node>) change -> {
         Set<Node> deadSeaScrolls = webView.lookupAll(".scroll-bar"); for
         (Node scroll : deadSeaScrolls) { scroll.setVisible(true); } });

        getChildren().add(webView);
    }
```

So, what can I do to remedy this problem? Any ideas. Thank you.